# Functions not being called in order?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm writing a program using python3 to simplify a report I use for work. It's not supposed to be architecturally sound or elegant, really I just bruted my way through it just to the point of it "working".

The methods by themselves do work fine, but when I enter them, they don't get called in order when I run them. I'm going to post the entire code here, because I know someone is going to ask something related to what's not show. Again, I wrote this really quickly just to work. It's not supposed to be anything built by a professional.

My question is, why are my methods not called in order. I do it this way so that the dictionary values are filled in by the input *and then* it's supposed to calculate the precentages. But what happens is, it calls the calculate percentage method out of order, so I'm stuck getting a division by Zero error (which yes is true when called out of order because the info needed technically hasn't been entered yet).

```
def enter_waste():
    while True:
        machine_selection = str(input('Please enter which machine you would like to enter the waste for: '))
        for element in machine_list:
            if machine_selection == element['name']:
                print('You Have Selected: {}'.format(element['name']))
                waste_input = int(input('Please enter the waste for this period: '))
                element['waste'].append(waste_input)
                if str(input('Do you want to continue? yes/no: ')) == 'no':
                    print("\nHere's everything as entered: \n")
                    for i, machine in enumerate(machine_list):
                        print(i, machine)
                return False

def enter_weight():
    machine_selection = str('Please enter which machine you would like to enter the produced weight for: ')
    for element in machine_list:
        if machine_selection == element['name']:
            print('You have selected: {}'.format(element['name']))
            weight_input = int(input('Please enter weight produced for this period: '))
            element['weight'] = weight_input
            if str(input('Do you want to continue? yes/no: ')) == 'no':
                print("\nHere's everything as entered: \n")
                for i, machine in enumerate(machine_list):
                    print(i, machine)
                return False

def calculate_waste_percentage():
    for element in machine_list:
        percentage = (sum(element['waste'])/element['weight']) * 100
        element['percentwaste'] = percentage
        print('Machine: {}\nWeight Produced: {;,}\n% of Waste: {}%'.format(element['name'], element['weight'], percentage ))
        return percentage
```

However, when I call them in order like this:

```
enter_waste(), enter_weight(), calculate_waste_percentage()
```

It will call `enter_waste()` but then jump to `calculate_waste_percentage` instead of running `enter_weight()`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I doubt that it should be behaving the way you mentioned

Comment: Why not call them one at a time rather than separated by commas?

Comment: Is this all of the code? When I try to run it I get not defined errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `input` call in your `input_weight()` function:

```
machine_selection = str(input('...'))
```

instead of

```
machine_selection = str('...')
```

As written, your code tries to set weight on a machine named "Please enter which machine you would like to enter the produced weight for: ", which does not exist.

I would suggest to also add a check that the machine name was entered correctly, to prevent this kind of error in the future.

Comment: Just `input('...')` is fine (i.e. automatically a string); this is Python 3.